# Router bit problem (falling out)

Tags: router-bit

I bought a router bit to make a nice edge on a board. I was able to do 2 sides but when I tried to do the 3rd side the bit kept falling out.

I tighten with the two nuts but the bit keeps falling out. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably share the make of the router, or at least the dimensions of the bit shaft -- add these details with an [edit]. Maybe review some previous Q&A related to router bits, such as my answer here: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/10677/5572 (But, no matter what I say, your tool manual will tell you the exact way they want you to attach cutters to the tool.)

Comment: It's possible that you got the wrong bit for your router and got lucky for the first two sides you worked on. 6mm and 1/4" shanks are _very_ close in size, but at the speeds routers spin, they're not close enough to safely hold the bit. That's why @jdv asked you to specify the exact make & model of the router - I'd suggest adding the make & model number of the bit, as well, just to be sure. It could also be an issue with tightening, for which the model number helps.